# OpenVPN: Setup Bridge Mode on Windows Server with Windows Client

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, openvpn, bridge

I have been using OpenVPN for quite some time  in routing mode.

I need to move to bridging as I require the client to be on the same lan.

The server has a fixed IP of 192.168.0.5 and a seperate DHCP server supplies address in the range 192.168.0.10 to 192.168.0.230.

I took my existing working (routing) configurations and modified them according to [the OpenVPN page](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/309-what-is-the-difference-between-bridging-and-routing) (**Bridge Server on Windows XP**).  In my case the server is Windows Server 2012 R2.

I entered the server-bridge line as

```
server-bridge 192.168.0.5 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.240 192.168.0.250.
```

On the client side I followed the instructions.

When I try to connect I get the following

```
Fri Dec 29 08:17:59 2017 WARNING: 'dev-type' is used inconsistently, local='dev-type tap', remote='dev-type tun'
Fri Dec 29 08:17:59 2017 WARNING: 'link-mtu' is used inconsistently, local='link-mtu 1589', remote='link-mtu 1557'
Fri Dec 29 08:17:59 2017 WARNING: 'tun-mtu' is used inconsistently, local='tun-mtu 1532', remote='tun-mtu 1500'
```

Any pointers / instructions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

My mistake.

For those who might have a similar situation here are the file compare changes on the server (server.ovpn.org was the router configuarion not the bridged one):

```
***** bridge mode
dev tap
;dev tun
;server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
server-bridge 192.168.0.5 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.240 192.168.0.250

***** router mode
;dev tap
dev tun
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
;server-bridge 10.8.0.4 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.50 10.8.0.100
```

---

On the client the change necessary was from

```
# the firewall for the TUN/TAP interface.
;dev tap
dev tun
```

to

```
# the firewall for the TUN/TAP interface.
dev tap
;dev tun
```